# Please Help. -- GUI wallet Daemon failed to start and can't find log or monerod and I can't see my money

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, daemon

When I open the wallet I keep getting this message "Daemon failed to start. Check your wallet and daemon log for errors. You can also try starting monerod manually."

I've scoured the monerod guide and the Internet and can't get this resolved. I can't find bitmonero in my file explorer.

How can I solve this?

If I click in monerod it opens for a second and then closes

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)